# Mechanical soup - form filling, working with a tricky HTML table

Tags: python, forms, mechanize, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to use mechanical soup to automatically fill and submit a time sheet for me.

This is what the form looks like:

[timesheet_form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fbTZ.png)

This is the relevant source code for that section of the page:

```
<FORM ACTION="bwpkteci.P_UpdateTimeInOut" METHOD="post">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="JobsSeqNo" VALUE="208138">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="LastDate" VALUE="0">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="par_restart" VALUE="Y">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="par_update" VALUE="Y">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="par_submit" VALUE="Y">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="par_recall" VALUE="N">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="EarnCode" VALUE="RSA">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="DateSelected" VALUE="20-FEB-2018">
<TABLE  CLASS="dataentrytable" SUMMARY="This user enters the time of day for the hours worked into this table in order for the system to calculate the hours.">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="delabel" scope="row" >Date:</TD>
<TD CLASS="dedefault">Tuesday, Feb 20,2018</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="delabel" scope="row" >Earnings Code:</TD>
<TD CLASS="dedefault">Regular Student Aide</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE  CLASS="dataentrytable" SUMMARY="This is the detail table where the user enters the time of the day for the hours worked in order for the system to calculate the hours.">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="deheader" scope="col" ><LABEL for=shift_input_id><SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Shift</SPAN></LABEL></TD>
<TD COLSPAN="2" CLASS="deheader" scope="col" ><LABEL for=timein_input_id><SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Time In</SPAN></LABEL></TD>
<TD COLSPAN="2" CLASS="deheader" scope="col" ><LABEL for=timeout_input_id><SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Time Out</SPAN></LABEL></TD>
<TD CLASS="deheader" scope="col" >Total Hours</TD>
</TR>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="LineNumber" VALUE="1">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="dedefault"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Shift" SIZE="2" MAXLENGTH="1" VALUE="1" ID="shift_input_id"></TD>
<TD CLASS="dedefault"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="TimeIn" SIZE="6" MAXLENGTH="5" ID="timein_input_id"></TD>
<TD CLASS="dedefault">
<SELECT NAME="TimeInAm" SIZE="1">
<OPTION VALUE="AM" SELECTED>AM
<OPTION VALUE="PM">PM
</SELECT>
</TD>
<TD CLASS="dedefault"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="TS_TimeOut" SIZE="6" MAXLENGTH="5" ID="timeout_input_id"></TD>
<TD CLASS="dedefault">
<SELECT NAME="TimeOutAm" SIZE="1">
<OPTION VALUE="AM" SELECTED>AM
<OPTION VALUE="PM">PM
</SELECT>
</TD>
<TD CLASS="dedefault"><p class="rightaligntext">0</p></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="5" CLASS="dedead">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD CLASS="dedefault"><p class="rightaligntext">0</p></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<P>
<TABLE  CLASS="plaintable" SUMMARY="This layout table is used to align buttons.">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="ButtonSelected" VALUE="Time Sheet">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="ButtonSelected" VALUE="Previous Day">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="ButtonSelected" VALUE="Next Day">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="ButtonSelected" VALUE="Add New Line">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="ButtonSelected" VALUE="Save">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="ButtonSelected" VALUE="Copy">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="ButtonSelected" VALUE="Delete">
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>
```

I am using mechanical soup to fill the form out and submit it.

```
#navigate to the timesheet page
browser.open(timesheetURL)
browser.get_current_page()

#select the form
browser.select_form('form[action="bwpkteci.P_UpdateTimeInOut"]')
form = browser.get_current_form()

#add required controls and set values for testing
form.new_control('text', 'shift', '1')
form.new_control('text', 'TimeIn', '08:30')
form.new_control('select', 'TimeInAm', 1)    #1 stands for PM
form.new_control('text', 'TS_TimeOut', '09:30')
form.new_control('select', 'TimeOutAm', 1) #1 stands for PM
form.new_control('submit', 'ButtonSelected', 'Save')
form.choose_submit('ButtonSelected')
browser.launch_browser()
browser.submit_selected()
browser.launch_browser()
```

I had to add new controls using new_control function because the TimeIn, TimeOut boxes did not show up when I checked by launching a browser.

This code does not work and I cannot figure out why. I thought maybe I was messing up the names or types of the controls that I was adding (maybe it didn't match with the actual input types and names of the form - I checked with a chrome extension and that too is not the case) as the save button would be clicked but the test values did not really register.

[check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwi6x.png)

This is what the browser looks like before the save button is clicked:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uldol.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwqV5.png)

It doesn't register!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MechancialSoup version 0.10.0, I was able to correctly parse your HTML snippet (as best I can tell). I don't see anything specifically that would cause this to fail for older version of MechanicalSoup, but perhaps try updating if nothing else works.

I used the following simple code:

```py
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open_fake_page(text)  #Here 'text' is the HTML snippet
form = browser.select_form('form[action="bwpkteci.P_UpdateTimeInOut"]')
form.print_summary()
browser.launch_browser()
```

The `print_summary()` method outputs all the form elements, which include the `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` boxes that were missing for you:

```
<input name="JobsSeqNo" type="hidden" value="208138"/>
<input name="LastDate" type="hidden" value="0"/>
<input name="par_restart" type="hidden" value="Y"/>
<input name="par_update" type="hidden" value="Y"/>
<input name="par_submit" type="hidden" value="Y"/>
<input name="par_recall" type="hidden" value="N"/>
<input name="EarnCode" type="hidden" value="RSA"/>
<input name="DateSelected" type="hidden" value="20-FEB-2018"/>
<input name="LineNumber" type="hidden" value="1"/>
<input id="shift_input_id" maxlength="1" name="Shift" size="2" type="text" value="1"/>
<input id="timein_input_id" maxlength="5" name="TimeIn" size="6" type="text"/>
<select name="TimeInAm" size="1">
<option selected="" value="AM">AM</option><option value="PM">PM</option></select>
<input id="timeout_input_id" maxlength="5" name="TS_TimeOut" size="6" type="text"/>
<select name="TimeOutAm" size="1">
<option selected="" value="AM">AM</option><option value="PM">PM</option></select>
<input name="ButtonSelected" type="submit" value="Time Sheet"/>
<input name="ButtonSelected" type="submit" value="Previous Day"/>
<input name="ButtonSelected" type="submit" value="Next Day"/>
<input name="ButtonSelected" type="submit" value="Add New Line"/>
<input name="ButtonSelected" type="submit" value="Save"/>
<input name="ButtonSelected" type="submit" value="Copy"/>
<input name="ButtonSelected" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
```

The elements missing for you were also displayed correctly when I use `launch_browser()`:

[image: imgur]

Comment: Thanks, it is weird that it worked for you. Anyways, I moved on to using selenium instead and it is waay better. USE SELENIUM!

Comment: @AshminBhandari While both MechanicalSoup and Selenium have overlapping use cases, MechanicalSoup does shine in certain situations.